# How to get different component ids for each dropdown in a row using jsf

Tags: jsf, drop-down-menu, components, identifier

I have data table like below:

```
<p:dataTable id="transactionTableID" binding="#{transactionReportBean.dataTable}" 
    value="#{transactionReportBean.summarizedDateWiseTransactionList}"
    var="transacVAR" rowKey="#{transacVAR.OID}" style="float:center;">

    <p:column headerText="#{build.reportSelection}">
        <p:selectOneMenu id="" value="#{transactionReportBean.summaryTxnReportSelected}"  >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="-Select One-" itemValue="-Select One-"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{build.matchedreport}" itemValue="#{build.matchedreport}"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{build.carryforwardreport}" itemValue="#{build.carryforwardreport}"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{build.exceptionreport}" itemValue="#{build.exceptionreport}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:commandButton  update="@form" value="Generate" ajax="false"
            actionListener="#{transactionReportBean.getReportSelected}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And an action listener method like below:

```
public void getReportSelected(){
    if(this.SummaryTxnReportSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("-Select One-")||this.SummaryTxnReportSelected.equalsIgnoreCase(null)){
        this.message = AlgoMessageHandler.getMessage(AlgoMessageHandler.USER_MSG, "ERR0048");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                                      this.getMessage(), AFTSConstants.BLANK_STRING));
    } else {
        this.selectedDtTxn= (TransactionsSummaryReportVO) dataTable.getRowData();
        System.out.println("listener called "+this.getSummaryTxnReportSelected()+" Selected transaction ID "+selectedDtTxn.getExecutionID());  
        String reportname = generateJasperReport(this.getSummaryTxnReportSelected(),AFTSConstants.SUMMARY_TXN_REPORT,this.selectedDtTxn);
        System.out.println("Report Name"+reportname);
        this.summaryReportStored= AFTSConstants.SUMMARY_REPORT_STORED_PATH+reportname+".pdf";
        System.out.println(this.summaryReportStored);
        this.setRenderGenerateButton(false);
    }
}
```

That method is about to generate report based on the dropdown item we are selecting. In my table I have 10 rows, each row contains one dropdown having 3 items. There is a "generate" button. After selection of dropdown items and clicking the "generate" button, for first 9 rows it doesn't give component IDs and for 10th row it's working.

Here the problem is not about generating report, the problem is JSF doesn't take different component IDs for each dropdown in each row. I tried `id="reportID"`, but no success. I tried to give row key value of table `rowKey="#{transacVAR.OID}"` as `id="#{transacVAR.OID}"`, but it throws an exception like "empty component id".

How am I supposed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with component IDs. Your problem is caused because you're binding submitted values of all rows to one and same bean property. JSF processes the submitted values based on the order the input elements appear in the tree. So, JSF will call the very same setter method with the submitted value for every single row until the last row is reached. You end up with the value of the last row. If you have placed a breakpoint on the setter method, you'd have noticed that it's subsequently been called with different values from every individual row.

You need to bind the value to the currently iterated row object instead.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{transacVAR.summaryTxnReportSelected}">
```